# Selectively read content of body in multipart/form-data request in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I have request with Content-Type: multipart/form-data, for example

```
POST http://myUrl/test
HEADERS
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxx

--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"

<content of file>
--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text1"

text value
...
```

There are different types of content sending in request body, but I want to get from this request only text values, and not deserialize file content, because when I read heavy request, I exceed default buffer capacity, and increasing buffer capacity is not an option.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Read Content-Disposition of each part. If it has a parameter called filename, then ignore, else read it normally.

Comment: Can you write some example? I am afraid that dividing into parts will require Reader, too, that has limited buffer, or am I wrong?

Comment: There's already an answer, please check.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't match my case, because my aim not to keep request body in memory. If I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read only text values from a `multipart/form-data` request in Spring WebFlux without deserializing file content.

Use the `Flux<DataBuffer>` to process the request parts one by one and extract the text values without fully loading the file content into memory.

Define a custom `PartProcessor`:

```
public class TextPartProcessor implements PartProcessor {

    private final Map<String, String> textValues;

    public TextPartProcessor() {
        this.textValues = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> processPart(Part part) {
        if (part instanceof FilePart) {
            // Ignore file parts
            return Mono.empty();
        } else if (part instanceof FormFieldPart) {
            FormFieldPart formFieldPart = (FormFieldPart) part;
            textValues.put(formFieldPart.name(), formFieldPart.value());
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getTextValues() {
        return textValues;
    }
}
```

The controller processes the `ServerWebExchange` to extract the text values:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>> handleRequest(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    TextPartProcessor textPartProcessor = new TextPartProcessor();

    return exchange.getMultipartResolver()
            .resolveMultipart(exchange)
            .flatMapMany(multipart -> Flux.fromIterable(multipart.getParts()))
            .concatMap(part -> part.content().concatMap(dataBuffer -> textPartProcessor.processPart(part)))
            .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(textPartProcessor.getTextValues())));
}
```

This will process the request parts and store only the text values in the `TextPartProcessor` instance. File parts are ignored, and their content is not deserialized, which should help you avoid exceeding the default buffer capacity.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I am dealing with Spring WebFlux and reactive case. And this solution requires to get all request in memory, and this is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @programmer sorry, didn't notice the spring-webflux tag. I edited the answer

Comment: hmm, yeah, but I am processing request in Spring WebFlux GatewayFilter. So, are you sure that if I transform request body into Flux<DataBuffer>, the full request body won't be put into memory? And if I transform request body into Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>, will the whole body put into memory?

Comment: Using `Flux<DataBuffer>`, the request body is not fully loaded into memory at once. Instead, it's processed in chunks. Using `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>`, the entire request body is deserialized into memory